# App installled but not showing on android emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I developed a Android app . Tried to run it but it is not showing on emulator though it has installed successfully

I get the following msg on console :

> ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=android.love/.MainActivity
>   }

the app should be seen after it is installed on emulator but it doesnt.

Comment: try adb kill-server and adb start-server in the terminal and then run again

Comment: Can you post more log messages